# Which equation is more suitable when a man lifts his leg in fluid (such as snow, sand or mud), Drag equation or Stokes's law, or other equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, drag

When a person lifts his leg in fluid (such as snow, sand or mud), what kind of resistance/viscous force will his leg encounter in the vertical direction, which equation is more suitable? Drag equation or Stokes's law, or is it another equation?

Comment: What does your research indicate? Try calculating the Reynolds number and checking the associated range of validity.